Dynamic Action triggering from an Interactive Report form Link
I have a form where I have a Dynamic Action trigger to populate a field called GC_NUMBERS_PULLED from a sql query,  and I have the DA when related to a change on a select list page item called TYPE .  This all works well from within the form, but when I link from the interactive report the DA allways triggers.
Here is a example of the IR

And when I goto edit the first record the DA triggers on the form and overwrites the data from the IR.

I tried adding a Client-side Condition to read up the P4_GC_NUMBERS_PULLED_RESULT field with a JavaScript expression apex.item("P4_GC_NUMBERS_PULLED_RESULT").getValue() !== "TRUE"  but that didnt work.

By default a DA action is set to fire on initialization. Sounds like that is what is happening
